# metodo Post http://127.0.0.1:4201/api/registro_cliente_admin net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED en Angular / Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, angular, api, http

Hola buenas tardes estoy tratando de enviar una petición a mi api desde el front y obtengo el siguiente error no se si ustedes logren ver alguna incongruencia con mi codigo maters de masters:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto es lo que tengo configurado en el backend:

**en app.js:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**en routes.js: donde van las rutas:**

```
api.post('/registro_cliente_admin', auth.auth, clienteController.registro_cliente_admin)
```

**este es el controller que iria con dicha ruta en clienteController.js:**

```
const registro_cliente_admin = async function(req,res) {

    if(req.user){
        if(req.user.role == 'admin'){
            var data = req.body

            //generamos un hash para encriptar la contraseña del cliente:
            encriptar_pass.hash("12345", null, null, async function(err, hash){

                if(hash){
                    data.password = hash; //creamos este campo llamado password en la data donde guardaremos a pass ya encriptada
                    let reg = await cliente.create(data);
                    res.status(200).send({data:reg});
                }else{
                    res.status(200).send({message:'No se pudo generar el hash de la contraseña, hubo un error en el servidor', data:undefined})
                }
            })
        }
    }   
}
```

y en el lado del frontend tengo este metodo del servicio que hace la peticion al api:

```
registro_cliente_admin(data:any, token:any):Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-type':'application/json', 'Authorization':token})
    return this.http.post(this.url+'registro_cliente_admin',data,{headers: headers})
}
```

**this.url vendria siendo:**

```
export var GLOBAL= { //tendra la url de nuestra api
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:4201/api/',
}
```

y ya este seria el metodo en mi componenete donde usaria ese servicio:

```
registro(registroForm:any){
    if(registroForm.valid){
      console.log(this.cliente)
      this._clienteServices.registro_cliente_admin(this.cliente, this.token).subscribe(
        response =>{
          console.log(response)
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      )
    }else{
      iziToast.show({
        title: 'ERROR',
        class: 'text-danger',
        titleColor: '#FF0000',
        position: 'topRight',
        transitionIn: 'bounceInLeft',
        message: "Los datos del formulario no son validos",
    })
  }
  }
```

el problema de cors lo soluciono aca en esta lineas de codigo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco mucho si pudieran ayudarme con este problema, llevo dos dias en esto cracks u.u. Estoy usando angular 17

Pd: el backend esta corriendo en el puerto 4201
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]